# Place y axis label in the right without changing the scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, yaxis

I have a plot [image]

and I would like to move the y axis label in the right but without changing the scale. Is there a way to do it? My code is:

```
ggplot(co, aes(x=model1,y = model2, color=ex)) +
    geom_point()
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "move in the right but without changing the scale"? You want to move the label to the right side of the plot but keep the "scale" aka the axis, the ticks and tick labels on the left?

Comment: I would like to remove the ticks in the y axis entirely, but I would like to keep the scale to the left. The only thing to move to the right is the label. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to first duplicate the y axis, then use theme options to get rid of the title on the left, the ticks and of course the labels on the right:

Using a simple plot based on `mtcars` as an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

# Move only the label to the right
p +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL)) +
  theme(axis.title.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

**EDIT** If you only want the title on the right, then switch the `position` and get rid of the text and ticks using `theme` options:

```r
# Move the label to the right and get rid of everything else
p +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: But there are still numbers in the left. Can I remove these?

Comment: I just made an edit to keep only the title on the right.

Answer (score 0):

moving the axis to the right hand side can be accomplished using

```r
+ scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
```